# Segmentation fault in firefox and chromium after installing updates

Tags: lubuntu, firefox, chromium, segmentation-fault

Lubuntu 18.04.1 running flawlessly in VirtualBox for about two years, had a few updates to install yesterday.

After the updates both firefox and chromium cannot start. When launching them from the terminal they just throw the error `Segmentation fault (core dumped)` .

syslog shows this:

```
[ 1117.595260] firefox[1589]: segfault at 1 ip 0000000000000001 sp 00007ffc7be98758 error 14 in firefox[7faebfd8f000+9a000]
[ 1117.595270] Code: Bad RIP value.
[ 1125.775419] chromium-browse[1592]: segfault at 2 ip 000056265394fb3c sp 00007ffe209f7608 error 4 in chromium-browser[56264fa77000+9618000]
[ 1125.775423] Code: 43 40 48 c7 43 40 00 00 00 00 48 89 45 e0 48 8d 55 e0 4c 89 f7 41 ff d7 48 8b 7d e0 48 c7 45 e0 00 00 00 00 48 85 ff 74 06 48 <8b> 07 ff 50 08 48 8d 7d d0 e8 16 06 52 fd 48 83 c4 18 5b 41 5e 41
```

The apt logs of yesterday's updates:

```
Start-Date: 2020-05-17  20:48:59
Commandline: aptdaemon role='role-commit-packages' sender=':1.263'
Install: libnetplan0:amd64 (0.99-0ubuntu3~18.04.1, automatic)
Upgrade: netplan.io:amd64 (0.98-0ubuntu1~18.04.1, 0.99-0ubuntu3~18.04.1), libapt-inst2.0:amd64 (1.6.12, 1.6.12ubuntu0.1), signal-desktop:amd64 (1.33.4, 1.34.1), libsystemd0:amd64 (237-3ubuntu10.39, 237-3ubuntu10.40), libpulsedsp:amd64 (1:11.1-1ubuntu7.5, 1:11.1-1ubuntu7.7), apt:amd64 (1.6.12, 1.6.12ubuntu0.1), pulseaudio:amd64 (1:11.1-1ubuntu7.5, 1:11.1-1ubuntu7.7), udev:amd64 (237-3ubuntu10.39, 237-3ubuntu10.40), libmagic1:amd64 (1:5.32-2ubuntu0.3, 1:5.32-2ubuntu0.4), libapt-pkg5.0:amd64 (1.6.12, 1.6.12ubuntu0.1), libudev1:amd64 (237-3ubuntu10.39, 237-3ubuntu10.40), nplan:amd64 (0.98-0ubuntu1~18.04.1, 0.99-0ubuntu3~18.04.1), libexif12:amd64 (0.6.21-4ubuntu0.1, 0.6.21-4ubuntu0.2), libmagic-mgc:amd64 (1:5.32-2ubuntu0.3, 1:5.32-2ubuntu0.4), libpulse0:amd64 (1:11.1-1ubuntu7.5, 1:11.1-1ubuntu7.7), chromium-browser:amd64 (81.0.4044.122-0ubuntu0.18.04.1, 81.0.4044.138-0ubuntu0.18.04.1), gir1.2-snapd-1:amd64 (1.49-0ubuntu0.18.04.1, 1.49-0ubuntu0.18.04.2), libpulse-mainloop-glib0:amd64 (1:11.1-1ubuntu7.5, 1:11.1-1ubuntu7.7), systemd-sysv:amd64 (237-3ubuntu10.39, 237-3ubuntu10.40), firefox-locale-en:amd64 (76.0+build2-0ubuntu0.18.04.1, 76.0.1+build1-0ubuntu0.18.04.1), chromium-codecs-ffmpeg-extra:amd64 (81.0.4044.122-0ubuntu0.18.04.1, 81.0.4044.138-0ubuntu0.18.04.1), libpam-systemd:amd64 (237-3ubuntu10.39, 237-3ubuntu10.40), systemd:amd64 (237-3ubuntu10.39, 237-3ubuntu10.40), apt-utils:amd64 (1.6.12, 1.6.12ubuntu0.1), iproute2:amd64 (4.15.0-2ubuntu1, 4.15.0-2ubuntu1.1), libnss-systemd:amd64 (237-3ubuntu10.39, 237-3ubuntu10.40), file:amd64 (1:5.32-2ubuntu0.3, 1:5.32-2ubuntu0.4), firefox:amd64 (76.0+build2-0ubuntu0.18.04.1, 76.0.1+build1-0ubuntu0.18.04.1), libsnapd-glib1:amd64 (1.49-0ubuntu0.18.04.1, 1.49-0ubuntu0.18.04.2), libjson-c3:amd64 (0.12.1-1.3, 0.12.1-1.3ubuntu0.2), chromium-browser-l10n:amd64 (81.0.4044.122-0ubuntu0.18.04.1, 81.0.4044.138-0ubuntu0.18.04.1), pulseaudio-utils:amd64 (1:11.1-1ubuntu7.5, 1:11.1-1ubuntu7.7)
End-Date: 2020-05-17  20:49:55
```

How do I even begin to trace the cause for this segfault? I assume one of the updated packages is to blame but which packages are shared by firefox and chromiun? Can I roll these updates back?

**Updated to add**:

1. Other applications still launch and run successfully, including Tor Browser, Signal, Sylpheed, AbiWord and others.
2. This is the output of `free -h` (as requested by @heynnema in the comments):

```
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           5.8G        290M        4.5G        2.7M        1.0G        5.3G
Swap:          2.0G          0B        2.0G
```

Comment: How much memory do you have assigned in the VM? Try starting Firefox with `firefox -safe-mode`. Report back.

Comment: @heynnema The VM has 6GB RAM. Starting Firefox in safe mode has no effect, same error. Other applications run just fine, including Tor Browser (based on Firefox), Signal, Sylpheed, AbiWord (never used it but it works).

Comment: Show me `free -h`. How many CPUs in the VM?

Comment: Can you boot to an older kernel in the VM and have Firefox/Chrome work then?

Comment: @heynnema I've added the output of `free -h`, the VM has 2 CPUs. Getting the same error when booting into 4.15.0-99 instead of 5.3.0-28.

Comment: Oh, my mistake. I should have asked for how much memory is in the host. Can you please try setting the VM guest memory to 2048, instead of 6G, and see if that has any effect. Report back.

Comment: @heynnema Already tried with 4GB and now with 2GB. Same result. Everything was working fine until that package update, can it be a coincidence?

Comment: Both Firefox and Chrome were updated in your last shown update. I don't know what to suggest. Please keep me posted.

Comment: @heynnema Thanks for trying to help. I removed both browsers (`apt autoremove`), ran `apt update` and installed them again. They're working now but the machine exhibits some weird behavior on reboot (loader stuck after splashscreen, but I can switch to tty). I guess something is very broken in this particular VM so I'm ditching it, but I also don't really like these unsolved mysteries so I'm keeping a snapshot of the broken state if anyone has further suggestions.

Comment: Does the machine get stuck on the Ubuntu logo with the cycling dots underneath? Are you using Wayland?

Comment: @heynnema It passes the logo and cycling dots, shows a blinking underscore at the top left for a second or two and then gets stuck with a permanent underscore. Not using Wayland.

Comment: Have you installed any video drivers? Which display adapter have you selected in the VM settings? Can you boot with nomodeset? Search here on AU for "black screen" and you'll see plenty of help for that problem.

Comment: @heynnema I've made no changes to VM settings before the problem started so I don't think that could be the cause. I restored a full backup of the VM (the virtual disk file) from about two weeks ago, let it run updates and everything is working ok so far. Haven't compared the packages yet but I think I'll leave it for now. Thanks again.